# Update enum value on correctly entered code

Tags: php, mysql

Been stuck for a bit. What I’m trying to do is update the value of an Enum row to yes when a verification code matches. Here the code.. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('dbconnect.php');

$verify_code = $_POST['vercode'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$verify_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $verify_code);

//Select SQL query against table
$query = "SELECT Verify_Code FROM Member WHERE Verify_Code = '$verify_code';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$update_query = "UPDATE Member SET Verified = 'yes' WHERE Verify_Code = '$verify_code';";
echo $update_query;
//header("Location:TwitchMain.php");
}
?>
```

The echo statment brings back
UPDATE Member SET Verified = 'yes' WHERE Verify_Code = 'Q#icm';
Which is the correct code.

Comment: please explain exactly what you want to do?

Comment: You should go back and read about how to use the mysqli extension and prepared statements. You are doing this wrong!

Comment: So what is your question here? That the enum value currently is not updated? Well, you do not execute that update query in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run SELECT query at all! Just run an update query, and if there is a member with this verification code in the database, he will be updated:

```
$verify_code = $_POST['vercode'];

$sql = "UPDATE Member SET Verified = 'yes' WHERE Verify_Code = ?";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $verify_code);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: user4035 you are my hero. Works YES...If your every in London i will buy you lots of beer..Cheers